# Square nxn matrix, finding inverse given an equation is satisfied

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are given that a square $N*N$ Matrix satisfies the equation $A^2 = 5A-6I$ where I represents the identity matrix.

there is two parts to this question
(a) Obtain an expression for $A^{-1}$
(b) Obtain an expression for $A^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

$A^2 = 5A - 6I, \tag 1$

we have

$A^2 - 5A = -6I, \tag 2$

whence

$-\dfrac{1}{6}(A^2 - 5A) = I; \tag 3$

we write this as

$A \left (\dfrac{1}{6}(5 - A ) \right ) = I, \tag 4$

from which we immediately read off

$A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{6}(5 - A). \tag 5$

Returning to (1), we multiply through by $A$:

$A^3 = 5A^2 - 6IA = 5A^2 - 6A; \tag 6$

we reduce this further, again using (1):

$A^3 = 5(5A - 6I) - 6A = 19A - 30I, \tag 7$

expressing $A^3$ in terms of $A$ and $I$.